# detecting the Beats Per Minute (bpm) of songs in mp3 and m4a formats in mac

Tags: audio, soundtouch

i am working on a mac on a mac application which needs the functionality of detecting the Beats Per Minute (bpm) of songs in mp3 and m4a formats. 
For detecting bpm we are using the codes from  http://www.surina.net/soundtouch but it is giving wrong bpm values for m4a files even though they are converted 
to mp3 or wav format using ffmpeg(Please note that bpm detection for mp3 files are working fine ). For detecting bpm we also tried the binary named SoundStretch which is also provided by soundtouch (http://www.surina.net/soundtouch). 
    Can any one explain what is going on?!. The m4a files even when converted to mp3 or wave are not working. Is any other open source libraries or classes  for bpm detection are available for mac?

Any one please give some directions

Comment: did you ever publish your project?

Answer (score 0):

[SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) is an open-source audio processing library.

Try contacting the author, [Olli Parviainen](http://www.surina.net/olli_personal.html), and explaining the problem with m4a formats to him.  He can either suggest a work around or fix his library.

Better yet, why don't you try and determine why the library code doesn't work with m4a formats.  Then you can submit a code patch to the author.

Comment: I know this is a very old post, I looked and `SoundTouch` and I can't see anywhere that it is able to detect BPM. It can change the tempo yes, but it can't detect the BPM.